# Has any same-sex common-law spouse claims been made in court?

Tags: united-states, marriage, same-sex-marriage

Same-sex marriage is [legal in 13 states](http://gaymarriage.procon.org/view.resource.php?resourceID=004857)

> California* (June 26, 2013), Connecticut (Nov. 12, 2008), Iowa (Apr. 24, 2009), Massachusetts (May 17, 2004) Delaware (May 7, 2013), Minnesota (May 14, 2013), New Hampshire (Jan. 1, 2010), New York (July 24, 2011), Rhode Island (May 2, 2013), Vermont (Sep. 1, 2009) Maine (Nov. 6, 2012), Maryland (Nov. 6, 2012), Washington (Nov. 6, 2012) Washington, DC legalized same-sex marriage on Mar. 10, 2012.

Some states have [common-law marriage](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/free-books/living-together-book/chapter2-4.html), with overlap between the two of Iowa, Rhode Island, W.DC.

> Alabama, New Hampshire (for inheritance purposes only), Colorado, Oklahoma, District of Columbia, Rhode Island, Iowa, South Carolina, Kansas, Texas, Montana, Utah

**In either of those states (or in Washington DC), has a claim of common-law marriage been made in court?**

Comment: While this has political implications it is not really a question about politics.  Beside that the question is really broad.   Many times the case does not get heard when someone tries to make a claim that does not have basis in the law.  So it would be hard to identify claims that have been attempted in the past since they would likely have been struck down.  I know there was one in Iowa but I think it was about he custody of the daughter that both claimed but was only biologically related to one. I am not sure if that would count here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it a question of Law, rather than of politics.